# python if condition for the first line of a table

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I have this table. This table is made through a loop.

```
for line in res.split('\n')[1:4]:
         list=line.split()
```

Results this table

```
 ID                  Prefix-list        
 1 |  ['ip', 'prefix-list', '2603', 'permit', '1.2.4.0/24']
 2 |  ['ip', 'prefix-list', '2603', 'permit', '2.2.4.0/24']
 3 |  ['ip', 'prefix-list', '2603', 'permit', '3.2.4.0/24']
 4 |  ['ip', 'prefix-list', '2603', 'permit', '4.2.4.0/24']
```

I want to use a another loop but i dont want to iterate through all the rows. so lets say if the first item of the row[0] is == "ip" then print all the rows.

```
for item in table1:
    if item[0] from the first row == "ip":
           print(item)
```

Any Idea?

Comment: and if not,,then what ?

Comment: if item [0] from the first row is "ip" print all rows

Comment: for example you want to write all the rows to a database. you can do a for loop for all the rows but if the table is big, you don't want to iterate through all rows. so if the first row match the condition you must be good.

Comment: are you looking for the `break` control flow statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work:

```
if table1.loc[0,'Prefix-List'][0] == "ip":
    print table1
```

Comment: The table above is created by another loop so i cant index without a loop!

Comment: While your code may solve the problem, consider adding a short description to help others understand how your code answers the question.

Comment: Sure, if I will make a habit of this from here on!!